# Let $X_{\alpha}$ be a closed subset of $\textbf{R}$. Show the intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ is also closed.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $I$ be a set (possibly infinite), and, for each $\alpha\in I$, let $X_{\alpha}$ be a closed subset of $\textbf{R}$. Show that the intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ is also closed.

**MY ATTEMPT**

We need to show that $X = \bigcap_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ contains all of its adherent points.

Let $X = \bigcap_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$ and $x$ be an adherent-point of $X$.

Therefore there is a sequence of points $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ entirely contained in $X$ which converges to $x$. Since each set $X_{\alpha}$ is closed and $a_{n}\in X_{\alpha}$ for every $n\geq m$ and $\alpha\in I$, this means that $x\in X_{\alpha}$ for every $\alpha$. Thus $x\in X$.

Hence we conclude that $X$ is closed indeed, and we are done.

Could someone tell me if I am reasoning correctly?

Comment: You supposed $x \in X$ while that was what you were trying to show, but I'm assuming that's a typo. Your proof is correct though. Only comment I can make is to explain why your last sentence implies $x \in X$ more rigorously. This is just for rigors sake.

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo. Thanks for the comment. I have also provided the proper argument which proves that $X$ is closed.

Comment: Your proof looks perfect now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have another approach:

We know that if $X_{\alpha}$ is closed then $X_{\alpha}^c$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence the arbitrary union of $X_{\alpha}^c , {\alpha}\in I$ is $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} X_{\alpha}^c$ which is open. By **De Morgan's Law** 
$\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} X_{\alpha}^c =\{\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} X_{\alpha}\}^c$. Therefore its complement is  $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} X_{\alpha}$, which is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.